# Spatial filter with a 1D signal

Tags: c++, matrix, smoothing

I have implemented in C++ several spatial filters to denoise 2D images (2D floating point matrices) and I'd like to see how they would perform with 1D signals (i.e. vectors of floats) but I'm not sure about the best way to do so.
One potential approach could be trying to conver the 1D signal into a kind of pseudo 2D matrix. For example, if the 1D signal is composed by 1024 values, I could create a 2D matrix consisting of 64 x 16 data points.
Alternatively, I could make copies of the 1D signal to fill a 2D matrix. But this could result in a very large data matrix.

Any advice?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is algorithm-dependant. There is no way we could answer without the code and algorithm.

Comment: The simplest spatial filter I have implemented is the median one with an NxM kernell, but this is just to give an example. The overall questionis how to apply a spatial filter (like an average, median, etc filters) to a 1D signal rather than an image.